# Stackpanel datatrigger for setting orientation based off children widths

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I know I can use a `WrapPanel` for this scenario but is there any way to achieve what I'm looking for.  I'd like to use a `StackPanel` as an itemspanel of a `ListBox` where the orientation is set to horizontal.  I can have the case where the children of the `StackPanel`extend past the width of the parent control/container.  So for instance if I have a `StackPanel` with 5 textblocks set to a horizontal orientation and then I take the window and drag the width making it smaller at some point the 5th `TextBox` will extend off the screen (hidden).  Its at this point I'd like some sort of data trigger to set the orientation to vertical, almost like a responsive design.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: maybe try `WrapPanel` instead of StackPanel first?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this?

You could handle the `SizeChanged` event. The following code sample should give you the idea. It sets the `Orientation` to `Horizontal` if the last element (`TextBox`) gets hidden and back to `Vertical` when the width increases.

```
private void ListBox_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
    ItemsPresenter ip = FindVisualChild<ItemsPresenter>(lb);
    StackPanel sp = FindVisualChild<StackPanel>(ip);
    UIElement lastElement = sp.Children[sp.Children.Count - 1];
    bool isLastElementVisible = IsElementVisible(lastElement);

    if (e.NewSize.Width < e.PreviousSize.Width && !isLastElementVisible)
        sp.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
    else if (e.NewSize.Width > e.PreviousSize.Width && isLastElementVisible)
        sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
}

private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName = null) where T : DependencyObject
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        var childElement = child as FrameworkElement;
        if (child is T && (childName == null || (childElement != null && childElement.Name == childName)))
        {
            return child as T;
        }
        else
        {
            var grandchild = FindVisualChild<T>(child, childName);
            if (grandchild is T)
            {
                return grandchild;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static bool IsElementVisible(UIElement element)
{
    if (!element.IsVisible)
        return false;
    var container = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as FrameworkElement;
    if (container == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("container");

    Rect bounds = element.TransformToAncestor(container).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, element.RenderSize.Width, element.RenderSize.Height));
    Rect rect = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, container.ActualWidth, container.ActualHeight);
    return rect.IntersectsWith(bounds);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox SizeChanged="ListBox_SizeChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <TextBox Width="100" Text="1" />
    <TextBox Width="100" Text="2" />
    <TextBox Width="100" Text="3" />
    <TextBox Width="100" Text="4" />
    <TextBox Width="100" Text="5" />
</ListBox>
```